# scraping html without htmlagilitypack

Tags: asp.net, .net

Due to the limitation of the system, i am not allowed to use htmlagilitypack as i dont have the rights to refer the library. So i can only use native asp.net programming language to parse page.

e.g. i want to scrap this page **https://sg.linkedin.com/job/google/jobs/**  to get the list of google jobs ( just an example, i am not really planning to get this list but my own company's) , i see they are under  how can i extra these jobs description and name.

My current codes are

```
System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();
try{
    System.IO.Stream myStream = client.OpenRead("https://sg.linkedin.com/job/google/jobs/");
    System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(myStream);
    string htmlContent = sr.ReadToEnd();
    //do not know how to carry on
}catch(Exception e){
    Response.Write(e.Message);
}
```

how can i carry on?

Comment: I'd strongly recommend to use the [LinkedIn API](https://developer-programs.linkedin.com/documents/job-search-api) instead.

Comment: linkedin API seem cannot getting company career page info and require admin rights which is currently controlled by headquarter at the moment

Comment: Unless I'm much mistaken you should be able to simply filter by `company-name`. This may result in a job list which still needs some cleansing but should be way easier than scraping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fetch that page and use a regular expression to isolate the useful parts. If you get real lucky, you may have a valid XML file:

```
var html = new WebClient().DownloadString("https://sg.linkedin.com/job/google/jobs/");
var jobs = new XmlDocument();
    jobs.LoadXml(Regex.Replace(Regex.Match(html,
        @"<ul class=""jobs"">[\s\S]*?</ul>").Value,
        @"itemscope | itemprop="".*?""", "")); // clean invalid attributes

foreach (XmlElement job in jobs.SelectNodes("//li[@class='job']"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(job.SelectSingleNode(".//a[@class='company']").InnerText);
    Console.WriteLine(job.SelectSingleNode(".//h2/a").InnerText);
    Console.WriteLine(job.SelectSingleNode(".//p[@class='abstract']").InnerText);
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: Parsing html as xml is not so robust; It is common that a html page is not a valid xml file,

Comment: @mortb, as I said, "if you get real lucky"; if you're out of luck, you can try to isolate the significant parts by using other regular expressions

Comment: hi, just curious how can i get the href value for  Response.Write(job.SelectSingleNode(".//h2/a").InnerText);

Comment: sorry, i have actually solved it using Attributes['href'].Value. Howeveer i faced another problem, now struggled for few hours. when i drill down to second page https://sg.linkedin.com/jobs2/view/77944876?trk=jserp_job_details_text  i want to grab the job description so i used this code     jobd.LoadXml(Regex.Replace(Regex.Match(detail,
        @"<div itemprop=""description"">[\s\S]*?</div>").Value,
        @"itemscope | itemprop="".*?""", "")); it is just not working, i am not sure why, can you help me

Comment: Your opening tag is missing an attribute and there are some `<br>` elements in there. Try this: `var description = Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace(Regex.Match(html,
                @"<div class=""rich-text"" itemprop=""description"">[\s\S]*?</div>").Value,
                @"itemscope | itemprop="".*?""", ""),
                @"<br>", "<br />")`

Comment: jobd.LoadXml( Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace(Regex.Match(html, @"<div class=""rich-text"" itemprop=""description"">[\s\S]*?</div>").Value, @"itemscope | itemprop="".*?""", ""), @"<br>", "<br />")); still getting root element is missing. strange

Comment: Try to isolate the problem: the match returns anything?